# How to integrate $\frac{x}{4-x}$ in my way?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'll first show a simple method that did work, and then I'll show the method that I'm trying to use.

**Process 1:**

$$\int\frac{x}{4-x}dx$$

$$[\text{Let}\ u=4-x\\\implies x=4-u \\ \therefore du=-dx]$$

$$=-\int\frac{4-u}{u}du$$

$$=-\int\frac{4}{u}du+u$$

$$=-4\int \frac{1}{u}du+u$$

$$=-4\ln|u|+u+C$$

$$=-4\ln|4-x|-x+4+C$$

$$=-4\ln|4-x|-x+C$$

This is a [valid](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7B4-x%7D) antiderivative.

**Process 2:**

$$\int\frac{x}{4-x}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}}{2^2-{(\sqrt{x})}^2}dx$$

$$[\text{Let}\ u=\sqrt{x}\\ \therefore du=\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}}]$$

Now, I'm stuck. How do I get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$? I have $\sqrt{x}$, but how do I get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: Substitutions are made to make intergral simpler not more complicated.Speaking of how to get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, you can multiply and divide with $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: $\frac d {dx} x^{1/2}=\frac  1 2 x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Another easier method would be to write the $x$ in the numerator as $x-4+4$

Comment: @RamanujanXV Oh I understand,

$$\int \frac{\frac{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}}{\frac{2^2-{(\sqrt{x})}^2}{\sqrt{x}}}dx$$

Comment: @RamanujanXV I tried using $u=\sqrt{x}$, and it seems like a dead-end to me. I reach $\int u^3\sec\theta d\theta$ and I can't do anything now, since I don't know integration by parts.

Comment: The integral after $u=\sqrt x$ is $\int \frac{2u^3}{4-u^2}\,du$. This can be done using partial fractions in a standard way (first using long division on this improper rational function). If you want to use a trigonometric substitution on this new integral instead, you would use $u=2\sin\theta$, but partial fractions works very well.

Comment: Observe that $$\frac{x}{4-x}=4\cdot\frac{1}{4-x}-1.$$